# After login successfully and killed the app when you reopen it I should see the dashboard (home page)

Tags: flutter, parsing, authentication, kill

After login in successfully and killed the app when I  reopen app  I should see the dashboard (home page)  using flutter and parse. I login successfully but after I kill the app it opens the login page, not the homepage. So is there a way to do this in the main ?

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy you can achieve this by various ways :

1. Hydrated bloc

2 ) SharedPrefrence package [package link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

I think you r beginner you can achieve this thing by using hydrated bloc and

shareprefrence which store user login status locally in users device so the next

time when user open mobile phone they will be redirect to that page where you want

but I will say to use shareprefrenced package which is very easy to use.

for eg: to save the use login status :

login()
async {

SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

preferences.setString('logedin', "yes");

}

and when you open your app

use this function :

checklogin()

async{

SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

```
    var logedin = preferences.getString('logedin');
```

}

if(logedin == "yes")

{

navigate.to(homepage())

}

else{

navigate.to(loginpage())

}

Comment: check my repository how I implemnt : https://github.com/amitsingh6391/Academic-master/blob/developer/lib/main.dart

Comment: the code in the link is using a firebase, and I am using parse not firebase so I will drop the code now and please tell me what I have to modify.

Comment: its does not mean which backend u r using this is totally different approach please follow the above code